# One homepage for Stack Overflow, Super User, meta and Server Fault?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, superuser, serverfault

On my user page for each site I can view my questions/answers for that site. Is there anywhere that I can view all of them at once?

It is inconvenient to have to view three pages every morning instead of viewing one.

Anyone?

Comment: Dupe many times over: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6375/so-family-combination-site-closed & http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6033/trilogy-portal-community-colloboration

Comment: @LanceRoberts The dupes seem to have been nuked!

Answer (score 4):

[Greasemonkey Script to show profile reputation and badges (from all SO sites) in the top toolbar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5933/greasemonkey-script-to-show-profile-reputation-and-badges-at-the-top-toolbar)

[image]

Comment: +1 for a good suggestion, but I find that bars take up too much screen real estate

Answer (score 3):

[Google Chrome extension to show reputation and badges from all SO sites in the top toolbar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37380/google-chrome-sofu-aggregator-extension) (based off of the original Greasemonkey script).

[screenshot http://img51.imageshack.us/img51/9580/barcd.png](http://img51.imageshack.us/img51/9580/barcd.png)

Comment: The second link is (effectively) broken (redirects to a generic page).